How to deal with colleagues making fun of my personal life in office?
30M here from India. So, I have these 4 colleagues say A, B, C and D in my team. One mistake I did was to tell them about some stories of my personal life. I was seeing 2 girls (at different times) in office, both of which have left the office a few months ago. Both of those girls turned out to huge red flags later on and destroyed my mental peace. I told these stories to those colleagues (whom I thought of as my good friends) out of frustration, which was a mistake on my part. Slowly, I got to realize that the shared stories of my personal life, which gave me immense mental pain has become a source of entertainment for them.
Professionally speaking, I have higher power, authority and position in the company than 3 of them (A, B, C), despite joining this organization a few months after them and I think this behavior is also due to some jealousy inside them for me. This is what I've realized with all of them:
Colleague A: 29M, An extravagant person, got recently married, is smart and think of himself as some big roast comedian as whatever topic people are talking about, he includes some witty one-liners to roast the people. This involved talking about their personal life. His behavior is such that since he is married, then he think of himself as more mature than me in terms of living life. He made fun of me in front of everyone by saying - this person attracts red flags and is a huge red flag himself. Has no sense of choosing girls.
Colleague B: 31M, Married, same age and experience as mine. If he is alone with me, he speaks decently. But with A, favours him in mocking me just because A is married and shares stories of his frustration with his wife with B. He gets too much excited, when A is trolling someone and while mocking me, starts speaking without even thinking what he is saying.
Colleague C: 26M, 4 years younger than me in age. Thinks of himself as a highly mature person just because he looks handsome and reads scriptures. Always blabbers Sanskrit verses to everyone around him by showing how smart he is. He also does too much trash talk with A and think of himself as his competition in roasting people. Has too much ego inside his mind. Told me once publicly that I am a big failure that I am unable to get any girl even after turning 30.
Colleague D: 29M, from the topmost college of India - IIT. Has bigger position than mine. A didn't invited him to his wedding but invited me and since then, he is in talking badly with me in a trolling fashion. In front of everyone, he said about me- "Look at this extremely unlucky guy, roaming around with married people and thinking this way he will get married. He should be ashamed despite being in 30s and sitting with married people."
Now, it's not that I didn't say anything in counter. I have also countered them by roasting them back multiple times but now I'm starting getting irritated as everytime, we sit together, all four of them, brings my personal life in the talk and starting roasting me by saying how big idiot I am and that's why, I am unmarried. My father doesn't earn much and I have financial responsibilities of my family and that's why, I spend the money carefully and they, despite knowing it, makes fun of me publicly by saying that how big miser I am and I won't even spend 200 to go by train. Although, they knew that 2 years ago, I purchased a home worth 80 lakhs and had loan over me and they made fun of it by saying why should a girl marry such loser who always thinks of paying EMI before spending money anywhere.
The common mentality of each of them is basically showing - "I AM BETTER THAN YOU". Basically, I have the ability to counter with even bigger roast but sometimes, they get hurt. I know that my default nature is to work more and talk less, especially when it comes to trash talk, which they do on a daily routine basis.
It's not that they are bad people. I considered them as my friends because they have supported me in the past also. But mocking me repeatedly on my personal life in front of everyone, is something which is becoming difficult to bear for me. I want to concentrate on my work and career goals rather than wasting time in thinking how will I roast this or that person.
I have warned colleague D (who isn't that close to me) that I won't speak anything against your personal life from now on and appreciate the same in return. We will only discuss work-related matters and nothing else. I have warned him in a chat and have kept a record so that I can take actions against him if I observe same behavior again.
Have also left the whatsapp group with A, B and C and some others in which there used to be a lot of trash talk and roasting each other.
But this behavior of colleagues is severely affecting my mental health.
Note: Requesting people to please be kind in comments. I am not in a state of getting abuses and trolls right now.

Lesson learned: keep your private and office life separate.

(whom I thought of as my good friends)

Which they apparently are not. So you may want to re-assess how you choose friends and evaluate people for personal relationships.
I understand, that this is a frustrating situation but the cat is out of the bag. Once a behavior has been established it's difficult to change.
Here is what you can do. This is a pretty standard approach for any type of bullying.
First step: talk to each person individually, face to face, and in private. Let them know that you that their behavior is unwanted. That it makes you uncomfortable, and that you feel its inappropriate and unprofessional and that you want it to stop. Do NOT accuse, blame or complain. Keep your emotions out of it, remain calm, friendly, and professional. This isn't an easy conversation to have, so it's good to script it and practice it with a (real) friend or in front of the mirror.
Talk about the impact that is has on you without blaming the other person. It's quite possible that they are not aware of how much grief they are causing you, so you need to tell them. If they are half way decent human beings, and still are at least "sort of" friends, they will take this to heart. Record carefully when this happens and what exactly was said.
Second step If that doesn't work, you need to cut them off hard. Don't interact at all unless it is required for work. Do not engage in any non-work related chat or social activity. If they try to drag you in to a conversation, just ignore them. If work talk drifts into private talk, remind them firmly that you are on the clock and that we really should focus on work.
With any luck, they will get the hint or just get bored if they don't get an emotional reaction out of you. So it's VERY important that you remain calm and professional and keep your emotions under control. Again, take detailed notes of any significant interaction where they don't behave professionally.
Third Step: If none of this works, you elevate to HR and/or your manager. Bring the notes that you have collected in steps 1 and steps 2, describe what has happened (with lots of factual details but no emotion or judging) and state that it negatively impacts your productivity and performance. You want to focus on work and the colleagues constantly trying to distract you with personal issues. Ask them how to proceed.

Just to add a point to @Hilmar's answer, no one can make you feel anything. Their behavior is on them. That doesn't mean that the situation isn't uncomfortable, but it is under your control. Taking control by not allowing other people's foolishness to bother you is very empowering. Good luck.


I have the ability to counter with even bigger roast but sometimes, they get hurt.

If you can't stand the heat, you must stay out of the kitchen.
If these interactions have stopped being fun, then you need to start being serious, stop participating, and announce that you think things have gone too far and you'd like it to stop completely.
Be prepared to stand firm and repeat this line a few times, if anyone falls back into patterns of mutual roasting which are already established.

But this behavior of colleagues is severely affecting my mental health. Note: Requesting people to please be kind in comments. I am not in a state of getting abuses and trolls right now.

You'll almost certainly have to show some firmity in this situation.
If you've already cracked mentally, then consider whether you need some time off or to find new employment where you can start again with a fresh social group, and consider whether there are pressures in your life wider than being roasted by colleagues which need to be resolved.
It might be that your employer's intervention would be able to bring the roasting to a hard stop, but that won't necessarily allow you to retain respect and friendships, if you've gone from dishing out roasts one day to complaining to HR the next. And it sounds to me like the loss of colleagues' respect and friendships would potentially hurt you as much as the roasts.
